# How to avoid duplicate records from a LEFT JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

```
id | name    
---|-------------
 1 | John
 2 | Franck
 3 | Peter
...
```

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
  iduser INT NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (iduser, email),
  );
ALTER TABLE emails 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (iduser)
REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

```
iduser | email
-------|---------------
     1 | john@hotmail.com
     1 | john@other.com
     2 | franck@gmail.com
...
```

I need to obtain the following result:

```
id | Name   | Email
---|--------|----
 2 | Franck | franck@gmail.com (just one of the two)
 1 | John   | john@hotmail.com
 3 | Peter  |
```

Using

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, emails.email
  FROM users LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.iduser = users.id
  ORDER BY users.name
```

returns both John rows, but I need only one of them (and also I need rows with no matching email present). How can it be done with a single query?

Comment: just add `group by users.name` before order by

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care which email is returned.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, max(emails.email)
FROM users 
 LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.iduser = users.id
GROUP by user.id, users.name
ORDER BY users.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, MAX(emails.email) AS Email
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.iduser = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DISTINCT` to return unique rows and `emails.email IS NULL` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.name, emails.email
FROM users LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.iduser = users.id
WHERE emails.email IS NULL
ORDER BY users.name
```